# Sveltekit throwing `ReferenceError: Request is not defined`

Tags: sveltekit, referenceerror, flowbite

I just created a new sveltekit app, installed flowbite component library and flowbite-svelte-icons and started writing some code, but when I checked my app on `localhost: 5173` all I saw was this message:

```
ReferenceError: Request is not defined
    at getRequest (file:///home/emmy/Documents/dev/public/water_watch/frontend/water_watch/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@2.0.4_@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.1_svelte@4.2.8_vite@5.0.10/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/node/index.js:101:2)
    at file:///home/emmy/Documents/dev/public/water_watch/frontend/water_watch/node_modules/.pnpm/@sveltejs+kit@2.0.4_@sveltejs+vite-plugin-svelte@3.0.1_svelte@4.2.8_vite@5.0.10/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:475:27
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The really weird thing is that I don't even see It on my terminal, it's only on the browser.

I didn't understand it so I removed all the code I wrote until it was only the default content when the project was created but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 13):

Okay, my problem seems to be the node version I am using, because although I setup the project with node 18, my machine (for some reason) switched to node 18. The conflicting node versions is probably the reason sveltekit was acting up, because now I've changed it and it all works fine.

Comment: similar happened to me, switching to node v18 fixed it

Comment: I'm unsure if I misunderstood, but it seems like there might be a typo as node 18 appears to be conflicting with itself. Initially, I utilized node 20 for the setup, but encountered the mentioned error. After that i switched to node 18 and everything worked as intended.

Comment: Same here, strangely node was using version 16 and when updating to 18, problem disappeared

You can check which version you are using with

```node -v```

Comment: oh, the beauty of a freaking platform which can't even really check its own `engines` config on `package.json`. I do miss PHP's Composer and its plain effectiveness of checking platform versions before accepting to run lol